# Spinner Issue in MVVM architecture android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata

When I rotate the screen the spinner reset though I am using MVVM architecture.
While setting value I set value in view model, but still spinner reset to its orignal state.

In Main Activity I have done this,

```
    GetBusinessPartners.setOnItemSelectedListener(object:OnItemSelectedListener{
        override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
         dealMealPreApproval.initsetSpinnerIndex(position)
        }

        override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }

    })

    dealMealPreApproval.getSpinnerValue().observe(this@DealMealPreApproval, Observer {
        GetBusinessPartners.setSelection(it)
    })
```

in view model i have done this

```
class MealPolicyViewModel : ViewModel() {

var businessPartners=MutableLiveData<ArrayList<BusinessPartnersModel>>()
var spinnerString=MutableLiveData<Int>()


fun initsetSpinnerIndex(valueOfSpinner:Int){
    spinnerString.value=valueOfSpinner
    Log.d("valueOfValueOFSPinner",valueOfSpinner.toString())

}

fun getSpinnerValue() : LiveData<Int>{

    return spinnerString
}
```

}

Comment: I think you are observing livedata wrong. Show me your code, so people can understand where you go wrong. I will not down vote this question. But please give more information about the question instead of asking in general.

Comment: @DươngMinh Kindly have a look.

Comment: Can you show me more about activity class, viewmodel class and how you initialize viewmodel?

Comment: @DươngMinh I edited the view model kindly have a look.

Comment: @DươngMinh I found the solution, kindly check my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For A small data like double, boolean, string, int you should use onSavedInstance like this, for large amount of data view model will be used.

```
 override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
    outState.putInt("MySPinner", GetBusinessPartners.getSelectedItemPosition());

}
```

Then getValue Like this in OnCreate Method

```
var counter=0

 if (savedInstanceState != null) {

        counter = savedInstanceState.getInt("MySPinner", 0)

    }
```

After Spinner Adapter call SetSelection and pass counter in it like,

```
   ArrayAdapter<BusinessPartnersModel>(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list)
            GetBusinessPartners.setSelection(counter)
```

Comment: That is also a solution. But if you implement MVVM architecture then I don't think you should. Instead try to find out what is the problem you are having with your viewmodel and livedata? Try my way, and if you still get the error, let me know.

Comment: I solve it using ViewModel.
Actually i was making mistake in setting position of Spinner in wrong place,
I should call setPostion of spinner after Adapter of the spinner,

Comment: Yeah. Nice try! The next time you post a question, try to give people your code. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

I still recommend you to use viewmodel with livedata in this case. Please check my solution.

In the viewmodel, you create the livedata that you want to store the data to display on the view. I still recommend using `MutableLiveData` to set data for live data, and `LiveData` for view to get data.

```
class MealPolicyViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val _businessPartners = MutableLiveData<ArrayList<BusinessPartnersModel>>()
    val businessPartners: LiveData<ArrayList<BusinessPartnersModel>> = _businessPartners

    private val _spinnerString = MutableLiveData<Int>()
    val spinnerString: LiveData<Int> = _spinnerString

    fun initsetSpinnerIndex(valueOfSpinner: Int){
        _spinnerString.value = valueOfSpinner
        Log.d("valueOfValueOFSPinner", valueOfSpinner.toString())
    }
}
```

In the view, specifically `MainActivity`, you initialize the viewModel through the lazy variable associated with the built-in extension of the activity-ktx library `by viewModels()`. Then you observe your livedata in `onCreate()`.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    
    private val viewModel: MealPolicyViewModel by viewModels()
    
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        viewModel.spinnerString.observe(this) {
            // TODO do something.
        }
    }
}
```

As you know, livedata will always observe the lifecycle of the view. In case you rotate the screen, the livedata will observe again when you finish rotating the screen.

Try my implementation and let me know if you still get the error.

Answer (score 0):

save the position in viewmodel,did u try that?but do not call it in spinner adapter after item selected, save it in onPasue and the save button(or ending to network button).
this is how u get position:

```kotlin
binding.spinnerLessonModelName.selectedItemPosition
```